# wpf WindowsFormHost

Tags: wpf, multi-touch, windowsformshost

Hi Every Body
Am Working With WPF Application
I Needed To Use MS Reports In My Application So I Used WindowsFormsHost
But The Problem Is That The WindowsFormsHost Can'nt Handle Touch Events
How I Can Handle Touch Events In My Report In WindowsFormsHost
Please I Need Ur Help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The question is as old as multi touch. As long as the control doesn't support it, you have to trick. Whether that's going to work depends on the control. The BING map control was successfully made to respond to touches. I think there's a touch enabled layer that takes touches and translates them to window messages. This can get a real mess.

Please keep in mind, that even if you can get such a solution to work, you won't get a touch optimized control. The control will probably have a *bad*, **bad** user experience...

If it's all about displaying data, I've described a possible alternative implementation on my post: for answer [How to display a PDF document in a Microsoft Surface application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021545/how-to-display-a-pdf-document-in-a-microsoft-surface-application/5063960#5063960)